# Android: SpeechRecognizer Listening Timeout

Tags: android

How to use SpeechRecognizer continuously without timeout. This is my code i am getting result on textview but this stops after listening few seconds. In my case i have to start until user don't stop it or it should stop after 15 to 20 minutes. if this is possible then please suggest me how to do. i want to increase timeout delay.

```
        public class VoiceService extends Service {
        String result;
        private SpeechRecognizer sr;


        class listener implements RecognitionListener {
            listener() {
            }

            public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
            }

            public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {Toast.makeText(VoiceService.this, "Listening", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

            public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
            }

            public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
            }

            public void onEndOfSpeech() {


         Toast.makeText(VoiceService.this, "Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }

            public void onError(int error) {
              }

                public void onResults(Bundle results) {
          ArrayList<String> matches = 
                  results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);

             if (matches != null){
               FragmentTwo.textViewresult.setText(matches.get(0));}

             }
                 public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {

                  }

                   public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
                        }

    }



                  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
                     throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
                       }


                     public void onCreate() {
                        super.onCreate();
                       Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", 
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         AudioManager amanager = (AudioManager) 
                                getSystemService("audio");
            amanager.setStreamMute(3, true);
            amanager.setStreamMute(1, true);

            onClickk();

        }

    public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            if (this.sr != null) {
                this.sr.destroy();
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, "Voice Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    public void onClickk() {
            if (this.sr != null) {
                this.sr.destroy();
            }
            this.sr = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
            this.sr.setRecognitionListener(new listener());
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.speech.action.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH");
            intent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.LANGUAGE_MODEL", "free_form");
            intent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.MAX_RESULTS", 1);
            this.sr.startListening(intent);
        }}
```

Comment: Have you searched over SO. this question has alredy been asked manytimes